# async call not effectiveness in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core

I want to test the effectiveness of asynchronous requests vs synchronous requests in ASP.NET Core 2.0. For this, I set the [Kestrel/Libuv `ThreadCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.transport.libuv.libuvtransportoptions) to 1 to force it to only use a single thread for all requests.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseLibuv(options =>
            {
                options.ThreadCount = 1;
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}
```

Then I write some simple code in the controller to call an asynchronous method. In the index action, I set the start time in the ViewBag, then call the `Doing` function asynchronously, and finally set the end time in the ViewBag.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Start = DateTime.Now;
        await Doing();
        ViewBag.Finish = DateTime.Now;

        return View();
    }

    public async Task Doing()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

View Code is:

```html
<div class="row">
    Start: @ViewBag.Start
</div>
<div class="row">
    Finish: @ViewBag.Finish
</div>
```

When I run the app and browse to the page in two browsers simultaneously, I expected that the request’s start time would be approximately equal. But when trying this, the second request is only started after the first request finished.

The output in two browsers is for example this:

```
Start: 10/10/2017 10:16:36 AM
Finish: 10/10/2017 10:16:43 AM

Start: 10/10/2017 10:16:43 AM
Finish: 10/10/2017 10:16:50 AM
```

What is wrong in my test or concept?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 2, the thread count is configured using `.UseLibuv(….)` instead of `.UseKestrel(…)`

Comment: @poke, thanks, but what your opinion obaut my problem?

Comment: I don’t have an answer yet. Btw. instead of those network calls, you could also simply do `await Task.Delay(5000)` to just wait 5 seconds, to achieve a consistent test that does not rely on the network.

Comment: FYI this was posted here as well: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6937

Comment: @Eilon, I add this issue to github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For test this I add the following code to the `Program Main` method, the number of worker threads is set 4.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(workerThreads: 4, completionPortThreads: 4);

    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

And add two simple query method to the controller, one simple, and the other is async. both of query takes 2 seconds for execution. I use [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) for run queries.

```
private void Query()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Execute("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';");
    }
}

private async Task QueryAsync()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        await connection.ExecuteAsync("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';");
    }
}
```

then I add three actions for sync, async, parallel test

```
public IActionResult Sync()
{
    Query();
    Query();

    return Ok();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Async()
{
    await QueryAsync();
    await QueryAsync();

    return Ok();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Parallel()
{
    var task1 = QueryAsync();
    var task2 = QueryAsync();

    await task1;
    await task2;

    return Ok();
}
```

I test my scenario by [West Wind WebSurge Load Tester](https://websurge.west-wind.com/) with the following config

> Execution Time: 60 seconds and Number of Thread that sends the requests: 10

This image is the result of my test that shown the number of successful requests, number of failed requests and the average time of the request per action.

[image: result of test]